# Highcharts only rendering one div

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

i was searching for an explaination here in this forum for my problem but couldnt find anything that helps me.
My problem is, that I want to get two solid gauges and one spline shown on my site but i can only see one chart at a time.

Here's my code where i guess the error is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Data</title>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/highcharts-more.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/solid-gauge.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|BenchNine|Poiret+One|Ropa+Sans|Ubuntu|Marvel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script>
        function target_popup(form){
        window.open('','formpopup','width=950,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
        form.target = 'formpopup';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- JS  -->
    <script>        
    $(document).ready(function() {
                var gaugeOptions = {
            chart: {
                type: 'solidgauge'
            },
            title: null,
            pane: {
                center: ['50%', '85%'],
                size: '140%',
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,
                background: {
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
                    innerRadius: '60%',
                    outerRadius: '100%',
                    shape: 'arc'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },
            // the value axis
            yAxis: {
                stops: [
                    [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
                    [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                    [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
                ],
                lineWidth: 0,
                minorTickInterval: null,
                tickPixelInterval: 400,
                tickWidth: 0,
                title: {
                    y: -70
                },
                labels: {
                    y: 16
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                solidgauge: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        y: 5,
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        useHTML: true
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        // The first gauge
        $('#yearlykm').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 13392,
                title: {
                    text: 'Distance for 2015'
                }
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: true
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Distance for 2015',
                data: [<?php include("../data/db_car.php");
                                            $sql = "SELECT sum(km) as SUMKM FROM tbl_data";
                                            $result = mysql_query($sql);

                                            while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                                            { 
                                                echo $line[SUMKM];
                                            }
                        ?>
                       ],
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                        ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                           '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">total km</span></div>'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' total km '
                }
            }]
        }));
        // The second gauge
        $('#totalkm').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                max: 80000,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total Distance'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Total Distance',
                data: [<?php include("../data/db_car.php");
                                            $sql2 = "SELECT sum(liters) as SUMLITERS FROM tbl_data";
                                            $result2= mysql_query($sql2);

                                            while ($line2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
                                            { 
                                                echo $line2[SUMLITERS];
                                            }
                        ?>
                ],
                dataLabels: {
                    format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                        ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span><br/>' +
                           '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">total km</span></div>'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' total liters'
                }
            }]

        }));
    });
    </script>
        <!-- JS -->
        <script>        
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'car',
                    type: 'spline',
                    marginRight: 0,
                    marginBottom: 25,
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: '',
                        x: -00 //center
                    },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: []
                    },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        style: {
                            color: 'white'
                        },
                        text: ''
                        },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#ffff00'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y +' €';
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'center',
                    x: 00,
                    y: -19,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '10px',
                        color: '#000000',
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    spline: {
                        fillColor: {
                    linearGradient : {
                        x1: 1,
                        y1: 0.1,
                        x2: 0,
                        y2: 0.2
                    },
                    stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                                    },
                    enableMouseTracking: true
                    }
                },
                series: [] 
            }

            $.getJSON("../data/data_car.php", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                options.series[1] = json[2];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });
        </script>


    <!-- HTML STARTS HERE -->
    <div id="header-wrapper">All Car Data</div>
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="../index.php">Home</a> |
        <a href="../phpmyadmin" target="_blank">PHP MyAdmin</a> |
        <a href="../data/fxall.php">All FX Data</a> |
        <a href="../data/travellall.php">All Travel Data</a> |
        <a href="../dev/">Travel Dev</a> |
        <a href="../dev/car.php">Car</a>
    </div>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="page-bgtop">
            <div id="page-bgbtm">
                <div id="page-content">
                    <div id="content">
                        <br>CHARTS<p>
                                <div style="width: 600px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto">
                                    <div id="yearlykm" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
                                    <div id="totalkm" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>
                                </div><p>
                                <div id="car" style="width:630px; height: 200px;"></div><p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sidebar">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Any help or pointer is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not post that code in a snippet or fiddle? As it stands, you're just pushing code debugging off onto someone else rather than asking a question that might help the community later...

Comment: Any chance `Highcharts.merge` is overwriting `guageOptions`? I'd go with `$.extend({}, guageOptions, { ... })` instead

Comment: Yes, try to use extend. Also, attach javascript errors from the console (if any). Also, which chart is rendered? Anyway, live demo would be great, like jsfiddle.

Comment: I found the problem now. I referenced to an older version of the highcharts.js. After replacing it with the latest and greatest it worked like a charm. Thanks anyhow for all your help!